How to Convert Dates from "Dec 01" to "2024-12-01" in amCharts5?
How to Convert Dates from "Dec 01" to "2024-12-01" in amCharts5?
I am using amCharts to create a dual-axis chart in Angular. The data I receive includes dates in the format "2024-12-01", but I need to convert these to the ISO format 2024-12-01 to use them on the X-axis of my chart but still its showing Dec 01 and other dates are converting normally
To handle this, I used the Date.parse function to convert the dates. However, I am unsure if this is the best approach or if there is a more efficient or standard way to achieve this in JavaScript.
export function createDetectionCountChart(config: any): void {

  // Create root and apply theme
  createRootAndSetTheme(config);

  // Create chart container
  let chart = config.root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(config.root, {
    panX: false,   // Disable horizontal panning
    panY: false,   // Disable vertical panning (remove scrolling)
    wheelX: 'none', // Disable wheel zooming horizontally
    wheelY: 'none', // Disable wheel zooming vertically
    pinchZoomX: false, // Disable pinch zooming horizontally
    pinchZoomY: false, // Disable pinch zooming vertically
    layout: config.root.verticalLayout,
    width: am5.percent(100),  // 100% width of its container
    height: am5.percent(100), // 100% height of its container
    background: am5.Rectangle.new(config.root, {
      fill: am5.color(getTheme() == 'dark' ? '#1b1d24' : '#fff'), 
      fillOpacity: 1,  
    }),
  }));

  // Set global date format for the root
  config.root.dateFormatter.set("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  // Determine theme-based colors
  const labelColor = getTheme() === 'dark' ? am5.color(0xFFFFFF) : am5.color(0x000000);
  const gridColor = getTheme() === 'dark' ? am5.color(0xFFFFFF) : am5.color(0x000000);
  const totalCountLabelColor = '#5249eb' // Total count color
  const uniqueCountLabelColor = '#36CB79' // unique labels color
  
  const data = config.data.map((item: any) => ({
    date: Date.parse(item.date),
    totalCount: item.totalCount,
    uniqueCount: item.uniqueCount
  }));

  const totalCounts = data.map(item => item.totalCount);
  const uniqueCounts = data.map(item => item.uniqueCount);

  const totalCountMin = Math.min(...totalCounts);
  const totalCountMax = Math.max(...totalCounts);
  const uniqueCountMin = Math.min(...uniqueCounts);
  const uniqueCountMax = Math.max(...uniqueCounts);

  // Create Date axis (X-axis)
  let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.DateAxis.new(config.root, {
    maxDeviation: 0.2,
    baseInterval: { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(config.root, {}),
    tooltipDateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
    gridIntervals:[{timeUnit: "day", count: 1}],
    dateFormats:{day:"yyyy-MM-dd", week:"yyyy-MM-dd",month:"yyyy-MM-dd",year:"yyyy-MM-dd"},
    extraMin: 0,
    extraMax: 0
   
  }));

  xAxis.get("renderer").labels.template.setAll({
    rotation: -45,
    centerX: 0.5,
    centerY: 1.5,
    fontSize: 10,
    dx: -40,
    dy: 10,
    fill: labelColor,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
  });

  xAxis.get("renderer").grid.template.setAll({ visible: false });
  xAxis.get("renderer").setAll({ maxCategoryWidth: 120 });


  // Create left Y-axis (for Total Count)
  let yAxisLeft = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(config.root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(config.root, {}),
    min: totalCountMin,
    max: totalCountMax,
    strictMinMax: true,
    numberFormat: "#a",
    // logarithmic: true,  // Enable logarithmic scale
    // logarithmicBase: Math.E, // Set the base of the logarithm (default is 10)
    extraMin: 0,
    extraMax: 0 // Prevent extra space on the top and bottom of the Y-axis
  }));

  yAxisLeft.get("renderer").labels.template.setAll({
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: "400",
    fill: labelColor
  });
  yAxisLeft.get("renderer").set("minGridDistance", 20);
  yAxisLeft.get("renderer").grid.template.setAll({
    stroke: gridColor,
    strokeWidth: 1
  });

  yAxisLeft.children.push(am5.Label.new(config.root, {
    text: "Total Count",
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: "normal",
    fill: totalCountLabelColor,
    rotation: -90, // Rotate the text to make it vertical
    x: am5.percent(0), // Position at the left edge (0% of the container width)
    y: am5.percent(80), // Position slightly down (10% of the container height)
    dx: -20, // Add offset to the X position
    dy: 0,
  }));

  // Create right Y-axis (for Unique Count)
  let yAxisRight = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(config.root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(config.root, { opposite: true }),
    min: uniqueCountMin,
    max: uniqueCountMax,
    strictMinMax: true,
    // logarithmic: true,  // Enable logarithmic scale
    // logarithmicBase: 10, // Set the base of the logarithm (default is 10)
    numberFormat: "#a",
    extraMin: 0.1,
    extraMax: 0.1 // Prevent extra space on the top and bottom of the Y-axis
  }));

  yAxisRight.get("renderer").labels.template.setAll({
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: "400",
    fill: labelColor
  });

  yAxisRight.get("renderer").set("minGridDistance", 20);
  yAxisRight.get("renderer").grid.template.setAll({ visible: false });

  yAxisRight.children.push(am5.Label.new(config.root, {
    text: "Unique Count",
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: "normal",
    fill: uniqueCountLabelColor,
    rotation: -90, // Vertical text
    x: am5.percent(0), // Position at the right edge (100% of the container width)
    y: am5.percent(90), // Position slightly up (90% of the container height)
    dx: 27.5, // Adjust X offset for rightward position
    dy: -20, // Adjust Y offset for upward position
  }));

  // Add Total Count series (Bar chart)
  let totalCountSeries = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(config.root, {
    name: "Total Count",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxisLeft,
    valueYField: "totalCount",
    valueXField: "date",
    clustered: false
  }));
  totalCountSeries.columns.template.setAll({ fill: am5.color('#5249eb'), width: am5.percent(40),tooltipText: "{valueY}" });

  // Add Unique Count series (Line chart)
  let uniqueCountSeries = chart.series.push(am5xy.LineSeries.new(config.root, {
    name: "Unique Count",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxisRight,
    valueYField: "uniqueCount",
    valueXField: "date",
    stroke: am5.color('#36CB79'), // line color
    fill: am5.color('#36CB79')   // 
  }));
  uniqueCountSeries.strokes.template.setAll({ strokeWidth: 2, tooltipText: "{valueY}" });
  uniqueCountSeries.bullets.push(() => am5.Bullet.new(config.root, {
    sprite: am5.Circle.new(config.root, { radius: 5, fill: am5.color('#36CB79'), tooltipText: "{valueY}" })
  }));

  // Set data for series
  totalCountSeries.data.setAll(data);
  uniqueCountSeries.data.setAll(data);

  // Add legend
  let legend = chart.children.push(am5.Legend.new(config.root, {
    useDefaultMarker: true,
    paddingLeft: 30
  }));
  legend.markers.template.setAll({
    width: 10,
    height: 10
  });
  legend.labels.template.setAll({
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: "400",
    fill: labelColor
  });

  legend.data.setAll([totalCountSeries, uniqueCountSeries]);
}


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/iVtIofj8.png


can you please be more specific like where exactly you want to convert date? Also, have you tried anything on your end first?

yes i have tried to override the date format but its not getting converted for the 01 dec

please add the code you have tried so that we can help you to correct it

i have updated my post can you please help?

How to Convert Dates from "Dec 01" to "2024-12-01"? Are you sure? How system know the year value to format from Dec-01? or do you want to mingle with current year? if current year, then what is the case for previous years?

from my response im getting date in this format "2024-12-01" and other dates are converting normally issue with the date of 01

can you please look into the attached image?

@SaiMahesh could you please just share a stackblitz or amcharts working example with the issue happening for debugging

you can preprocess the dates into iso fromat before passing them to the charts
    const data = config.data.map((item: any) => ({
    date: new Date(item.date).toISOString(),
    totalCount: item.totalCount,
    uniqueCount: item.uniqueCount}));

You are already setting the global date format in config.root.dateFormatter.set("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd"); but you also should
do it in xaxis lables and tooltip explicitly
xAxis.get("renderer").labels.template.setAll({
    rotation: -45,
    centerX: 0.5,
    centerY: 1.5,
    fontSize: 10,
    dx: -40,
    dy: 10,
    fill: labelColor,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
    dateFormats: { day: "yyyy-MM-dd" }
    });

    


i think we have to send the date in timestamp for the dateAxis
